# How to check if a character is a not a part of number or URL in string?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Update: I've simplified the question (the initial task was sentence splitting).
The code below should defined each character "." as a delimiter but output for each character FALSE:

```py
import re

delimiters = ['!', '?', '.']
def is_delimiter(char):
    number = str(re.findall("\d+\.\d+", text))
    if char in delimiters and char not in number:
        return True
    return False

text = "Hello. I'll come back on 12.09."
for char in text:
    print(char, is_delimiter(char))
```

I need to character "." after "Hello" is to be defined as delimiter and output TRUE.
The character in "12.09" (assume that 12.09 is a number) is to be defined as NOT delimiter and output FALSE.

So what i have:

```
o False
n False
  False
1 False
2 False
. False
0 False
9 False
. False
```

What I want to have:

```
o False
n False
  False
1 False
2 False
. False
0 False
9 False
. True
```

Thanks!

Comment: it is not your full code.

Comment: give some examples too to understand your problem, inputs and output desired.

Comment: Give us a sample value of `text` that illustrates your problem.

Comment: what you mean by ""not a part of number:""

Comment: just use `re`'s `split`: `res = re.split(r"[!?]|(?<!\d)\.", text)`

Comment: The code works well if i just check if a character is "!", "." or "?" with _is_delimiter_ function. The thing is, i should in this function also check if a character not a part of a number or URL. For example: _"Hello. I come back in 12.09"_ - The result should be as two sentences: **"Hello"** and **"I come back in 12.09"**, not "Hello", "I come back in 12", "09"

Comment: This basic input/output example should in **the question itself**, not a comment that people are less likely to see...

Comment: I've edited the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should only really have to check to see if the character after the delimiter is a white space to tell if it's not at the end of the sentence. No re needed.

```
delimiters = ['!', '?', '.']
def is_delimiter(char, next_char):
    if char in delimiters:
        if next_char is not None:
            if next_char == ' ':
                return True
        else:
            return True
    return False

text = "Hello. I'll come back on 12.09."

for i in range(0, len(text)):
    char = text[i]

    j = i+1

    if j < len(text):
        next_char = text[j]
    else:
        next_char = None

    print(char, is_delimiter(char, next_char))
```

Comment: Now it goes better :) but still defines each point "." as a delimiter: the point after "Hello" - TRUE, point after "12" in "12.09" - also TRUE

Comment: ohh I see what you're trying to do. You don't even really need to use re for that. I'll edit the above post.

Comment: It check if a next char is a whitespace, but anyway it's also a solution :) Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

Seems like you just need to check for that in the conditional statement in `is_delimiter()`. You can check to see if your `char` variable is part of a list where you define your delimiters like so:

```
import re

delimiters = ['!', '?', '.']

def is_delimiter(char, text):
    number = str(re.findall("\d+\.\d+", text))
    if char in delimiters and char not in number:
        return True
    return False
```

But there's a better way to do this just using this regex expression:

`(?<!\w\.\w.)(?<![A-Z][a-z]\.)(?<=\.|\?)\s`

So in python,

```
sentences = re.split('(?<!\w\.\w.)(?<![A-Z][a-z]\.)(?<=\.|\?)\s', text)
```

Here it is in action: 
[regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/nG1gU7/27)

Comment: Can i use this regex expression within the function is_delimiter()?
To check if a character match this pattern (?<!\w\.\w.)(?<![A-Z][a-z]\.)(?<=\.|\?)\s

Comment: The code above also doesn't work as by me, for example:
['Hello', ' How are you', ' I come back on 12.09. Looking forward to see you.']
It's just define all points as not delimiter

Comment: Oh, well given what you posted above it was very hard to see that you were working with a list. You could iterate through your list with a for loop ( `for t in text:` ) and replace `text` with `t` in that last snippet I posted.

Answer (score -1):

Maybe this can help?

```
text = "anfbbs12!.sdf"
symbols = ["!",".","?"]

for letter in text:
    if letter in symbols and not letter.isnumeric():
        # code
    else:
        # more code
```

Comment: Your code makes no sense... if a letter is `in symbols` than it is one of `!, ., ?` so it will always be `not isnumeric`... So bottom line this just checks for symbols